# How to get address of function or global variable from its name in executable elf file for C?

Tags: function, variables, elf, dlsym

How to get address of function or global variable from its name in executable elf file? 
dlsym() can get address of function in  dynamic library file. But it does not work for executable elf file. Before I parse the ELF file ,I want to check whether there is one library that provide same function for executable elf file? Then I can get address of function or global variable from its name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compile the executable file with `-Wl,-E` (or it's various variants such as `-export-dynamic`), then the linker will produce a dynamic section for the executable, and you can access its symbols with `dlsym` and a `NULL` handle, e.g., `dlsym (NULL, "foo")`.